# Read file from linux os using cat and ignore newline characters

Tags: bash, cat

I am trying to use the command line to read a file, cut a certain number of characters from that file and then write it back to the file. However, I don't want any newline characters.

What I saw is that if I use `echo -n "Example Text" > tmp_file` I am able to write the data to the file without any newlines. However, when you use cat to read a file you get the newline file.

How, can I read a file, grab the string that I need and write it back to a file, while not being bogged down with the newline.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ~are you really getting new line? or just thinking like that? check `cat tmp_file | xxd`~ I misuderstood that you don't want the last newline character. `-n` only removes trailing new line.

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of newlines in what's read from the file, or avoid adding a newline at the end of what you write to the file, or both, or something else? If you're trying to avoid adding a newline, use `printf '%s'` instead of `echo -n` (for example, `printf '%s' "Example Text"`) (see [this unix&linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using `tr`:

```
echo -n "Example Text" | tr -d "\n" > tmp_file
```

Or `sed`:

```
echo -n "Example Text" | sed -z "s/\n//g" > tmp_file
```

And if you want to remove only the newlines at the end of the input, it can be done like this:

```
echo -e "Example Text\nSome more Text\n\n" | sed -ze "s/[\n]*$//g" > tmp_file
```

The output will be

```
Example Text
Some more Text (without newline here)
```